# leaflet Check if there is a circle already on map

Tags: leaflet

I wanna know for example if a circle is already on map ?

`let circle = L.circle([lat, lng], quake.size);`

`map.hasLayer(circle);`

doesn't work, always returns false even if we already have this circle on map

Comment: Can you show an example ?

Answer (score 0):

> always returns false even if we already have this circle on map

No, it doesn't.

http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/mum/edit?html,console,output